# as an option is selected from the select menu populated data to next select menu from database.How to show "No data availabe" when no data found

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

M using ajax to populate select tag drop down menu. Selecting an option from one select tag will fetch data to the next select tag from database through ajax.. M able to get the result but when an option is selected for which no data is available in database i want to show some message in the select tag as " No data found for this selection"

` $(document).ready(function(){

```
    $("#sel_block").change(function(){
        var blockid = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'getZone.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {block:blockid},
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(response){

                var len = response.length;

                $("#sel_zone").empty();
                for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
                    var id = response[i]['id'];
                    var name = response[i]['name'];
                    var temp="No Data Found";

                    if(response.length)
                    {
                        $("#sel_zone").append("<option value='"+id+"'>"+name+"</option>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         $("#sel_zone").append('<option value="">' + emptyMessage + '</option>');
                    }


                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5axz.png)
Write Now its showing blank when there is no data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before looping through response you have to check its length. Didn't check this code, but it should work

```
var len = response.length;

$("#sel_zone").empty();
if(len == 0){
    $("#sel_zone").append('<option value="">No Data Found</option>');
} else{
    for( var i = 0; i<len; i++){
        var id = response[i]['id'];
        var name = response[i]['name'];
        $("#sel_zone").append("<option value='"+id+"'>"+name+"</option>");
    }
}
```